# How can wordpress works without transactions?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

In wordpress there are tags. So when a user insert a post, wordpress have to do at least 2 queries ( insert in the POST table and insert in the POST_TAG table ).

How can this works good without using transactions ( and so innodb ) ?

I am wondering this because I am designing a similar project with POST and TAG tables and a many to many relationship and I can't use innodb.

Comment: I would guess because they don't care if the insert to the tags table fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress isn't often used in environments where there are a lot of concurrent users posting articles at the sametime. Where as, an open blogging platform like [blogger.com](http://www.blogger.com) is used by millions of users at once.

So a collision of transactions isn't likely to happen for the average Wordpress user.